# ROS_PACKAGE_PATH for catkin beginners

Tags: ros, catkin, begginer-tutorials, ros-package-path, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Section 1.2.2 of beginner level tutorial "8.Using rqt_console and roslaunch" says:

*If roscd fails, remember to set the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable in your terminal. Then the commands will look like this:

**$ export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/<distro>_workspace/sandbox:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH***

I followed the catkin based tutorial and found out that this doesnt work. I use **ros-groovy on Ubuntu 12.10**.I tried

**export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/catkin_ws/src:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH**

which solved the issue. I guess whats given in the tutorial is based on rosbuild. Perhaps a mention on catkin based command would help beginners.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60424/ros_package_path-for-catkin-beginners/) by [Maheshwar Venkat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4623/maheshwar-venkat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you ever `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` (or `source ~/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash`)? That step should set your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maheshwar Venkat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4623/maheshwar-venkat/) on 2013-04-10**:
does it remain set even if i restart my computer or something ?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-10**:
No, you have to `source` the setup.bash file each time you open a terminal. If you are going to be working with the same workspace for a long time you can put the `source /path/to/setup.bash` command in your ~/.bashrc file which will run each time you open a terminal.

**Comment by [Maheshwar Venkat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4623/maheshwar-venkat/) on 2013-04-10**:
resolved and understood. thanks.!